Glob pattern with AND condition for eslint plugin boundaries
I'm trying to setup eslint boundaries plugin and need to specify glob pattern for paths. But its not clear how to write the pattern which will cover the following case:
The pattern should match the following conditions:
src/features/[any folder]/[MUST HAVE index.ts AND (ui folder OR model folder OR lib forlder)]

I wrote the following pattern:
  {
    "pattern": ["src/features/*/(lib|model|ui)/**", "src/features/*/*.ts"],
  }

But it breaks on following paths src/features/project/index.ts because src/features/project/ contains only index.ts and other folders but does not contain ui | model | lib folders.
